# Выравнивание элементов по краю в XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, разметка

Я работаю над UserControl, который включает в себя один основной элемент и четыре вспомогательных. Я бы хотел, чтобы вспомогательные элементы располагались на границе основного, но не знаю, как этого добиться.

[image]

Я использую вот такой код разметки:

```
<myTypes:VoltageConnector HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<myTypes:VoltageConnector HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<myTypes:VoltageConnector HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<myTypes:VoltageConnector HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

Но в этом случае элементы встают не на границу, а возле неё с внутренней стороны:

[image]

Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отрицательные маргины спасут вас:

```
<Border BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="2" Margin="50">
    <Grid>
        <Panel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-17"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Style>
        </Panel.Resources>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image]

Comment: Ну это для фиксированной ширины. Для нефиксированной ещё придётся ваять конвертер.